# BigQuery asks me to group rows by 2 identical columns

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a dataset for information on some warehouses and another on the orders received. I wanted to report on the number of orders fulfilled by each warehouse, so I joined them together using a JOIN statement. I also wanted the warehouse names in the `warehouse_alias` column to appear alongside the states they are in, so I used CONCAT.

As you can see in the tables, both `warehouse_id` and `warehouse_alias` columns are unique, which means I can use either of them to identify a warehouse. However, when i used GROUP BY to group the warehouse by `warehouse_id`, BigQuery throws this error:

> SELECT list expression references warehouse.warehouse_alias which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:9]

I know this has something to do with the CONCAT that i used, but couldn't grouping them by `warehouse_id` be enough? Since each warehouse has a different ID *and* alias?

My code:

```sql
SELECT  
CONCAT (warehouse.warehouse_alias, ', ', warehouse.state) AS Warehouse_name,
COUNT (warehouse.warehouse_id) AS Num_orders,
(SELECT
  COUNT(*)
  FROM `analyze-data-project-391208.warehouse_orders.orders`) AS All_WH_num_orders

FROM `analyze-data-project-391208.warehouse_orders.warehouse` AS warehouse
JOIN `analyze-data-project-391208.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders
ON warehouse.warehouse_id = orders.warehouse_id
GROUP BY 
  warehouse.warehouse_id
```

[The Warehouse table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeQbA.png)

[The Orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI8Pb.png)

Answer (score -1):

When you use aggregate functions (like COUNT) then all the columns in your SELECT clause need to either be aggregate functions or be in your GROUP BY clause.

In your SELECT clause you have

```
CONCAT (warehouse.warehouse_alias, ', ', warehouse.state)
```

so this needs to be in your GROUP BY clause as well e.g.

Also, given your description of your requirements, your SQL doesn't look correct and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the sub-select. If you just want the count of orders by warehouse then the SQL would be something like (I'm guess you have a column called orders.orders_id):

```
SELECT  
CONCAT (warehouse.warehouse_alias, ', ', warehouse.state) AS Warehouse_name,
COUNT (orders.orders_id) AS Num_orders,
FROM `analyze-data-project-391208.warehouse_orders.warehouse` AS warehouse
JOIN `analyze-data-project-391208.warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders
    ON warehouse.warehouse_id = orders.warehouse_id
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT (warehouse.warehouse_alias, ', ', warehouse.state)
```

Comment: Okay, I think grouping by `Warehouse_name` _only_ would be much easier to understand. I did and it gave the same result. Also thank you, I did make a grave mistake at `COUNT (warehouse.warehouse_id) AS Num_orders`, it should have been `orders.order_id` instead. But why it still gave the same results with the wrong code?